# Omitting comma from previous line if element not present in the source using freemarker

Tags: json, xml, freemarker

I am doing xml to json conversion using freemarker. My Xml is following

```
<ResponseMetadata> 
   <ResponseCode>HS000000</ResponseCode> 
   <ResponseDescriptionText>Success</ResponseDescriptionText> 
</ResponseMetadata>
```

I am using following ftl for conversion.

```
<#assign data =  xml['child::node()']>
{      
  "ResponseMetadata":{  
     <#if (data.ResponseCode)?has_content>"ResponseCode":"${data.ResponseCode}",</#if>
     <#if (data.ResponseDescriptionText)?has_content>"ResponseDescriptionText":"${data.ResponseDescriptionText}",</#if>
     <#if (data.TDSResponseDescriptionText)?has_content>,"TDSResponseDescriptionText":"${data.TDSResponseDescriptionText}" </#if>   
  }
}
```

I am getting follwing output where comma (,) is printing after second element beacuse third element is not present in the XML source.

```
"ResponseMetadata":{  
     "ResponseCode":"HS000000",
     "ResponseDescriptionText":"Success" ,   
  }
}
```

I want the output without comma if element does not found like following:

```
"ResponseMetadata":{  
     "ResponseCode":"HS000000",
     "ResponseDescriptionText":"Success"   
  }
}
```

My question is how to ommit comma when next element is not present in the source xml. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change XML to JSON, you can simplify your code, list over all nodes in xml and use `sep`:

```
<#assign data =  xml['child::node()']/>
{      
    "ResponseMetadata":{  
    <#list data?children as field>
        "${field?node_name}":"${field}"<#sep>,</#sep>
    </#list>
    }
}
```

And the result:

```
{      
    "ResponseMetadata":{  
        "ResponseCode":"HS000000",
        "ResponseDescriptionText":"Success"
    }
}
```

Look for more freemarker build-ins functions for XML [here](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_node.html)

Comment: Or even when it's not a such straightforward case, the approach should be somewhat similar: Don't print the items directly, instead first put them into a list, and then print the list. It's because only then can you know if there will be a next element to print.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am getting some garbage like @Text before in every response like this
{"ResponseMetadata":{@text":"",ResponseCode":"HS000000",
@text":"",ResponseDescriptionText":"Success",@text":""}}

Comment: I see @Text is node name. I filter out the element node like this  
<#if field?node_type == 'element'>"${field?node_name}${field}<#sep>,</#sep></#if>
but still comma is coming at the end because ?children brings other type of node too. Also all the variable are string here since in the xml everything as string. 
Seems this approach is not working for me. I need to consider data type also. Any other suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve this problem. The solution would be to declare a sequence and add the element that has content and parse as a list. The solution code is following

```
<#assign data =  xml['child::node()']>

    {      
      "ResponseMetadata":{  
      <#assign y = []>
         <#if (data.ResponseCode)?has_content>
                <#assign var1>"ResponseCode":"${data.ResponseCode}"</#assign>
                <#assign y = y + [ var1 ] />
         </#if>
         <#if (data.ResponseDescriptionText)?has_content>
             <#assign var2>"ResponseDescriptionText":"${data.ResponseDescriptionText}"</#assign>
             <#assign y = y + [ var2 ] />
         </#if>
         <#if (data.TDSResponseDescriptionText)?has_content>
             <#assign var3>"TDSResponseDescriptionText":"${data.TDSResponseDescriptionText}" </#assign>
             <#assign y = y + [ var3 ] />
         </#if>   

        <#list y as x>
            ${x}<#sep>,</#sep>
        </#list>

      }
    }
```

Comment: This solution is working perfectly for me, can we make it approved solution?